# Issues starting Mongo, hangs at, connecting to: test

Tags: mongodb, terminal

I am new to mysql, and just started to use mongodb
I recently installed mongodb using:

brew install mongodb

So, when I run mongodb, it gives:
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log

And when I type mongodb in a new tab, it shows:

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.7
connecting to: test

And it gets stuck here.

my main directory-> /Users/Myname

Why does this happen?

Comment: what the log file contains and what is your operating system?

Comment: OS X 10.9, mongo.log contains logs of the server restarting...

Comment: plz me give the last page of /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log

Comment: To clarify, what command are you typing in? It should be `mongod` to start the database server, and `mongo` to access the shell.